# Interpretation of a 3 Variable System of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm a high school student, and, of course, this week is finals week. For my Algebra 2 semester final, we have been permitted to take the test home and collaborate with others.
This final can be viewed here: http://issuu.com/final1/docs/4__-5___s1_exam___welcome__14-15

As you can see, there are 5 problems, each with multiple parts. I have completed everything fairly easily except the last part of the last question, 5g. While this part is related, in a way, to every other part of question 5, it is most closely related to e and f.

The ordered pairs I came up with for part e were: $(2, 624)$, $(3, 720)$, and $(4, 704)$.
Thus, the equations I created were $624=4a+2b+c$, $720=9a+3b+c$, and $704=16a+4b+c$.
The solution to this system is $(-56, 376, 96)$.

All this was easy enough to calculate, but part g has me stumped. I've been thinking for a while, and I can't discern any relation this solution has to the box. Knowing my teacher's personality, I'm afraid it might be a sort of joke. If it isn't, however, I'd like to get it correct. So, if any of you can find the answer to part g, I would highly appreciate it. I'm sorry about the formatting, and thank you in advance.